# Добавить условие в массив

Tags: php, массивы

Мне надо разграничить доступ к функционалу в зависимости от типа лицензии у пользователя.

Есть строка кода для вывода данных:

```
$CAMPAIGN_TYPE = array(0, 'Image', 'Video', 'IFrame', 'External Website', 'Optin Form', 'Footer Bar', 'Scarcity Bar', 'Header Bar');
```

Нужно добавить такое условие для вывода:

1. если тип лицензия BASIC - должно быть выбрано только значение 'Image';
2. если все остальные типы лицензии - должны быть выбраны все значения (как это, в принципе, работает и сейчас, но для всех типов лицензий, включая BASIC).

Сделал так, но чувствую, что неправильно, да и не работает это:

```
if (@$_SESSION['licence_type'] == BASIC) {
  $CAMPAIGN_TYPE = array(0, 'Image');
} else {
  $CAMPAIGN_TYPE = array(0, 'Image', 'Video', 'IFrame', 'External Website', 'Optin Form', 'Footer Bar', 'Scarcity Bar', 'Header Bar');
}
```

Comment: @Kromster, html/php (5.6). Необходимо, чтобы CAMPAIGN_TYPE принимал одно или все значения в зависимости от типа лицензии. Может быть нужны еще какие-нибудь данные?

Comment: "но чувствую, что неправильно, да и не работает это" - вот это вот расшифруйте еще плиз

Comment: Не работает, потому что все равно продолжает выдавать все варианты, вне зависимости с какой лицензией я захожу...

Answer (score 0):

```
 $CAMPAIGN_TYPE = array(0, 'Image', 'Video', 'IFrame', 'External Website', 'Optin Form', 'Footer Bar', 'Scarcity Bar', 'Header Bar');   
 if(@$_SESSION['licence_type'] == BASIC)) 
       $CAMPAIGN_TYPE = array(0, 'Image');
```

просто переопределяешь переменную если тайп  базик без лишних else

Comment: Спасибо! Но не работает ((   все равно продолжает выдавать все варианты, вне зависимости с какой лицензией я захожу

Comment: Смотри значение $_SESSION['licence_type'], ты его кстати сравниваешь с константой, там не строка случайно должна быть?

Comment: Прошу прощения, а что это значит?

Comment: $_SESSION['licence_type'] == 'BASIC' скорее всего должно быть